# How to customize the copy/paste shortcut(default to ctrl/shift+insert)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, x11, xfce

I want to remap change the copy/paste shortcut from CTRL/SHIFT+Insert to CTRL+C/V in Xfce4. I known where I can add a global keyboard shortcut but I don't known which command should I use.

I've tried use xdotool to send key strikes. like

```
xdotool key ctrl+Insert
xdotool key Control_L+Insert
```

these won't work for me when setting as a keyboard shortcut, but they work in terminal. I don't know why.

Directly using a command or sending a key strikes are both acceptable solutions IMO.